# jQueryRotate not working

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am using jQuery Rotate to rotate the image but I can't figure out the reason why it's not working . I am including everything in the code but no luck . I am testing it on FF.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#image").rotate(180);
            });
        </script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image" style="margin: 100px 100px">
    </body>
</html>
```

Even I paste the code as it is from this thread [Having trouble getting jqueryrotate to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886980/having-trouble-getting-jqueryrotate-to-work) but no luck .

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BjYSD/ your code seems to be working

Comment: thanks for the reply .your link shows me its working , but when i open html file in my browser it didnt work ..

Comment: Did the console show any error..?

Comment: @ A.V i cant belive this on file it shows me nothing but on console it shows me '});â€‹' at the end of script . I rewrite the script and it works now thanks alooot

Answer (score 0):

I'm author of jqueryrotate and have to say that... well.. I got some problems with handling margin across many browsers I would advice you to put IMG into DIV and add this margin to DIV container. Unfortunaltely its an outcome of a heavy workarounds for CANVAS/VML solution that makes hard to take into account all possible cases (like margin for example).